# Find answer to expression within a list

Tags: python, list, expression

What is the most pythonic way to find the answer to an expression within a list? (evaluated from left to right, and in terms of operator precedence)

```
an_expression = [1, '+', 6, '//', 2]
answer = # 4

another_expression = [2, '-', 2, '*', 3, '+', 1]
answer_2 = # -3
```

Comment: Build a AST and evaluate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#eval) after making sure the expression is safe to evaluate, e.g.:

```
>>> operators = {'+', '-', '*', '/', '//'}
>>> expr = [1, '+', 6, '//', 2]
>>> if all(isinstance(x, int) or x in operators for x in expr):
...     print(eval(''.join(map(str, expr))))
... 
4
```